# sqlplus spool file with parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, spool

I have an sql file which is executed from command line, it works fine.

`sqlplus username/password@DBInstance @filename.sql`

My **filename.sql** looks about this:

```
set colsep ';'
set echo off
set feedback off
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set termout off
--set define off
set serveroutput on
set verify off
set autoprint off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 9999 
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';

spool STOCK.csv

SELECT ils.item
  || ';'
  || ';'
  || ';'
... 
Where loc = store_no
--store_no is typed in the script by hand--
...;
spool off
exit
```

After running sqlplus command, i get csv file with all selected rows, that are delimetered by ';' for specific value **store_no**, everything works fine. What i need is to send **store_no** as a parameter and for each parameter get new corresponding *csv file. So i could run, for example:

`sqlplus username/password@DBInstance @filename.sql 3`

And get *csv file where **store_no** = 3. 
I've searched for some solutions and didn't get the right one. I think i'm not far with this solution:

```
set colsep ';'
set echo off
set feedback off
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set termout off
--set define off
set serveroutput on
set verify off
set autoprint off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 9999
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';

spool STOCK.csv

DECLARE
store_no number := &1;
BEGIN

SELECT ils.item
      || ';'
      || ';'
      || ';'
    ... 
    Where loc = store_no
    ... ;
END;
/
spool off
exit
```

As output i get this: PLS-00428: **an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement**

Considering to such output, i need variable to store there whole output. But i don't know how to keep correctly reading *csv file using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
Can anyone please help how to perform this task? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a PL/SQL block for this.

Say you have a table like this:

```
create table yourTable(loc number, item varchar2(10));
insert into yourTable values (1, 'one');
insert into yourTable values (2, 'two');
insert into yourTable values (3, 'three');
```

With a script **test.sql** like this:

```
set colsep ';'
set echo off
set feedback off
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep off
set termout off
set serveroutput on
set verify off
set autoprint off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 9999
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';

spool d:\temp\STOCK.csv

SELECT item
      || ';'
      || ';'
      || ';'
    from yourTable 
    Where loc = &1;
spool off
exit
```

and this call:

```
sqlplus usr/pwd@DB @test.sql 3
```

you get a file like:

```
three;;;
```

If you want to spool to different files based on the parameter value, you can edit the spool command, for example this

```
spool d:\temp\STOCK_&1..csv
```

will give a file **STOCK_3.csv** if you pass `3` as parameter value

Comment: It worked, thank you! Maybe you know how to pass parametres into spooled filename? I need, for example, to create *csv file with such name: STOCK_{store_no}_{current_date}_{launch time}.csv, where {store_no},{current_date},{launch time} are parametrs. I know how to do this using bash and --sed-- command, but in that case it will generate *.sql file for each launch_time. What i want is to run everything using only one script.

Comment: You can use the parameter quite the same way; just edited to show you an example